# Only edit visible lines in sparse tree view

Tags: org-mode, search

Consider the following org-mode document

```
* Foo
** bar1                            :g1:
** bar2                            :g2:
** bar3                            :g1:
** bar4                            :g2:
** bar5                            :g2:
** bar6                            :g1:
```

Now I do `C-c / m` and search for `g1`. The view will then be

```
* Foo
** bar1                            :g1:
** bar3                            :g1:
** bar6                            :g1:
```

as desired.

I would wish to be able to edit those three lines, e.g. by creating a selection and doing `C-x r t` in order to add `foo` to all three headings. If I do that, `foo` will also be added to the hidden headings. Furthermore, for some strange reasons, automatic newlines are inserted, the lines will look like

```
** foo
bar1                            :g1:
```

My questions are:

- How can I edit several headings at the same time?
- Where does that line break come from?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

1. `M-s o` for occur-mode, search for `g1`
2. `C-x o` to change to the other window
3. `e` to enable editing
4. Edit by rectangle tagging or similar
5. `C-c C-c` to switch back to occur-mode

However, I am still interested in a better or more elegant solution.